# WSO2 ESB, cant fetch records or perform actions with SQL Server database

Tags: .net, wso2, sql-server-2014, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB in our .net application. I successfully connected to our SQL Server 2014 database, but I am not able to fetch records or perform any action. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you get records using ESB? did you used db lookup mediator? if then post the sequence you created?

Comment: Hi Mark, Could you please check `wso2carbon.log` inside the `<ESB_HOME>/repositiry/logs` directory for any errors? Please let us know if there any errors. Also please let us know your ESB version and the operations, which you have tried to performed.

Comment: My solution: 1. include WSO2 DSS features inside WSO2 ESB 2. Create DS as you need using local transport protocol 3. expose those DS as proxy services.

Answer (score 1):

ESB is not designed to fetch records from database.

If u use DBLookup Mediator. 
As per documentation:  **The DBLookup mediator can set a property from one row in a result set. It cannot return multiple rows**

As well DBLookup inject received data into property,  and those are not visible in soap document, they are just resides in axis engine as property element.

U can log those properties:
Let's say DBLookup define result elements id, name, age, then u can log values received from database as:

```
<log>
   <property name="ID" expression="get-property('id')" />
   <property name="NAME" expression="get-property('name')" />
   <property name="AGE" expression="get-property('age')" />
</log>
```

Possible solution to get several row:

There is pattern in ESB which can help. Y can manage DBLookup to return data as string, which contains all primary key separated by comma. Those keys are referrs to rows, those need to get from DB. Then using **for-each** mediator and xslt function split, iterate over keys and make another **DBLookup** call to get actual data corresponds to that key. Even after that u have to inject those data in property into message itself.

This really hard to make work, hard to debug.

Much easier to install DSS feature create data_service and make request to it when u need data using any of mediator **Call, Send**

Comment: Thank you! We are downloading DSS and I think this is the solution we missed :)  Appreciate everyone's response.